# Find closest locations without using the same location twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of people with their locations. I want to match the closest people to each other. One person can not be matched twice.

I have the first part, but I can't figure out how to avoid matching the same person twice.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `_person` (
  `id_person` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(30,28) NOT NULL,
  `long` decimal(30,27) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_person`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=351 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Select:

```
SELECT a.id_person, a.name, b.id_person, b.name, 111.1111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(a.lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.long - b.long))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.lat))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.lat)))) AS distance_in_km,
         CONCAT(a.id_person, '_', b.id_person) AS match_id
FROM  _person a CROSS JOIN _person b
WHERE a.id_person < b.id_person;
```

Restults in:

```
id      name                id      name                distance_in_km      match_id
157     Rubin Kouba         192     Francie Lansford    1.3349701041430388  157_192
122     Pearly Godin        157     Rubin Kouba         7.621880803034831   122_157
122     Pearly Godin        192     Francie Lansford    8.604980125095778   122_192
18      Morris Haines       70      Jenelle Eurich      28.469537174712613  18_70
97      Fabiola Lister      122     Pearly Godin        32.29419525788823   97_122
97      Fabiola Lister      157     Rubin Kouba         37.710767037180126  97_157
97      Fabiola Lister      192     Francie Lansford    39.040035483275396  97_192
201     Chastity Clonts     334     Glinda Rosch        59.90641505745896   201_334
```

Rubin Kouba is already matched on the first row, and shouldn't be matched in the second row.

Is this possible in (my)sql?

Thank you

Comment: I think your query is behaving as you expect.  In row one, Rubin Kouba's closest neighbor is Francie Lansford.  But this doesn't preclude that Pearly Godin's nearest neighbor is also Rubin Kouba.  If you proceed down your line of thought, it might result in names being completely dropped from the result set.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a way to exclude if the person was already matched.

Comment: Look closely at your data.  If you apply this algorithm, then `Pearly Godin` will vanish because both of her two matches were already previously matched.

Comment: So what's the logic?

Comment: Perhaps you want the shortest path that takes in every user exactly once - an np complete problem (see Djikstra)

Comment: Actually, you don't get duplicate results. `Rubin Kouba` is matched with `Francie Lansford` in the first row, but `Francie Lansford` won't be matched with `Rubin Kouba` and as for the pair `Pearly Godin` and `Rubin Kouba`, it **should** be a match since `Rubin Kouba` is his closest neighbor. Except of course you are trying to create a route, in which case your query is incomplete since you should at least have a start point.